# Why is there an apparent "high priority" on reciting all 7 Consolation Haftarot?

Tags: minhag, rosh-chodesh-new-month, haftarah

Last week, I looked at the back of my shul's *Tiqun Kor'im* (I forgot which version it is, offhand) and noticed a long paragraphs explaining the different customs of what happens when Shabbat parshat *R'eh* coincides with Rosh Hodesh Ellul or *Machar Chodesh* (1st day of Rosh Hodesh on Sunday) Ellul. Some customs say to read the parshat *R'eh Haftarah* and others say to read the Rosh (or Machar) Chodesh Haftarah.

It seems that the most common Nusach Ashkenaz practice that I have seen is to read the Rosh Hodesh haftarah on R'eh. The haftarah from R'eh is made up together with the reading of the Haftarah of Ki Tetze - i.e. Ki Tetze is read first followed by the haftarah of R'eh, as the two texts are next to each other in *Yeshayahu*.

I'm curious as to why high priority is given to asserting that all 7 haftarot should be read and why there is a debate about it at all? The only other conflict that I am aware of that has a similar debate is if *Breishit* coincides with Rosh Hodesh or Machar Chodesh.

There are other times when Rosh (or Machar) Chodesh coincides with other haftarot, such as:

- Chanukah
- Parshat Sheqalim
- Parshat Hachodesh
- Mas'ei or Matot/Mas'ei (2nd week of Haftarot of "Punishment". This is a rare occurrence as this would happen when 1st day Pesach was on Sunday.)

In these cases, from what I have seen, Rosh or Machar Chodesh haftarah is eliminated and the haftarah for the special day is said. (Though, I have seen some congregations include the 1st and last verses of the Rosh / Machar Chodesh haftarah at the end.)

For those that decide to override R'eh with Rosh Hodesh, what would be so bad about skipping one of the 7 Consolation Haftarot? Why is there this minhag to try to make it up? And, if, in fact, these haftarot are so important, then, why not follow the predence set by the others and just not do Rosh Hodesh?

Comment: "For those that decide to override R'eh with Rosh Hodesh" Do you mean the opposite? It seems the common custom is that the 7 Consolation are of very low priority and that's why Rosh Chodesh pushes it off but doesn't push off other ones

Comment: what other set of haftoros are you comparing the 7 of consolation to? the Tur introduces the 7 of consolation and the 2 of return by saying that the whole year the haftara is of the theme of the torah portion of the week, besides for these weeks when the haftora follows the theme of the time, i.e. consolation. what similar set of haftoros exist?

Comment: @DoubleAA You could view it either way, actually. The reason I marked it "high" is that even though many Nusach Ashkenaz customs will say the Rosh Hodesh one in R'eh, they still try to make it up by attaching it to the end of *Ki Tetze*. Thus, at some point it is said. That's as opposed to not making it up at all. I'm uncertain what the priority is with Mas'ei / Rosh Hodesh. It's a rare occurrence.